# What is wrong if cellForItemAtIndexPath: is called in didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I called `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method. The result was that `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` was only called one time per cell. So I can tap the first time on a cell, then I can tap on another cell, but if I tap on the first cell again the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is not called anymore (but all other "new" cells).

Now I'm not calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` anymore and now `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` works as expected. But why I'm not allowed to do this? Any reasons for this?

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: You should show your implementation of `cellForRow` and `didSelect`

Comment: if you are getting your cell in didselectRowAtIndexPath. You can get it this way 

`CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: are you calling the collection view method or your delegate method (`cellForItemAtIndexPath:` or `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`)?

Comment: @RahulVyas: I tried to use the cell for the passthrough views for the popover. Therefore I need a `UIView` object, which is generated by the datasource.

Comment: @KIDdAe: Really nothing special here. I only call the methods as described (I commented out the rest and it still occurs). Of course my whole setup behinde is much more complex but that doesn't help with the issue here. I could post the code in C#, but it wouldn't help as much.

Comment: @Wain: I'm calling `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. So I'm asking the datasource and not the collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection view is caching instances of cells for you and you dequeue them when you create the cell at an index path. The collection view is making some assumptions about what's going on when you do this, so if you start making multiple requests for cells at the same index path strange things start to happen. Sometimes this results in visual issues, sometimes interaction issues.

If you want to get the cell at a specified index path you should ask the collection view directly instead of using your own delegate method, this will give you the existing cell on screen rather than a new cell.